# Multiple select box to show search

Tags: javascript, mysql, search, search-engine

I want to show the search value by day, month by selecting in multiple select box.
I want to search in mysql to show all the product posted by that day and that month and it must be a live search.

[image]

My Database already have day, month, year

My Code:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
      <div class="multiselect">Day
      <?php
      $i = 1;
      $daypresent = "";
      while ($i <= 31) {  
          $daypresent .= '<label><input type="checkbox" value="'.$i.'" name="day['.$i.']">'.$i.'</label>';
          $i++;
         }
      echo $daypresent;
      ?>
      </div>
        </td>
        <td>
      <div class="multiselect">Month
        <?php
      $i2 = 1;
      $monthpresent = "";
    while ($i2 <= 12) {  
      $monthpresent .= '<label><input type="checkbox" value="'.$i2.'" name="month['.$i.']">'.$i2.'</label>';
      $i2++;
     }
    echo "<br/>".$monthpresent;
  ?>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
  jQuery.fn.multiselect = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        var checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
        checkboxes.each(function() {
            var checkbox = $(this);
            // Highlight pre-selected checkboxes
            if (checkbox.prop("checked"))
                checkbox.parent().addClass("multiselect-on");

            // Highlight checkboxes that the user selects
            checkbox.click(function() {
                if (checkbox.prop("checked"))
                    checkbox.parent().addClass("multiselect-on");
                else
                    checkbox.parent().removeClass("multiselect-on");
            });
        });
    });
};



  </script>
```

Comment: What advantage does this solution offer over a standard datepicker?

Comment: i want to select all day and month or some to sales report

Comment: Some? Like 'February, September, November' or '1st, 5th, 9th'?

Comment: right :v search by day and month only the value in select will show